# Polymer Starter Kit app-drawer & app-header showing on top of fullscreen video

Tags: javascript, youtube, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I am using Polymer Starter Kit, and I have included a few YouTube videos in one of my pages with `<google-youtube>` elements. When I click to view a video in fullscreen mode, the side `app-drawer` and top `app-header` persist and cover the video. How do I hide the drawer and header?

`app-drawer` usage:

```
<app-drawer paper-drawer-toggle class="appDrawer" id="menu" on-tap="closeMenu">
  <div class="appDrawerBackground">
    <app-toolbar class="appDrawer">Menu</app-toolbar>
    <hr class="menuLine">
    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a class="homeMargin" name="home" href="/home">Biography</a>
      <hr>
      <a name="view1" href="/acting">Acting</a>
      <hr>
      <a name="view2" href="/produce">Directing / Producing</a>
      <hr>
      <a name="view3" href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </div>
</app-drawer>
```

`app-header` usage:

```
<app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <div title>
      <img class="headerImg" src="/images/toolbar-logo.png">
    </div>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>
```

Screenshot:

[image: SCREEN SHOT]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, you need to include code samples in your question if you want to be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer Starter Kit's root layout element, `app-drawer-layout`, contains the `app-drawer` and the `app-header`, both of which have their own [stacking context's with a positive `z-index`](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) -- one that is higher than the `<iron-pages>` child, which presumably contains the `<google-youtube>` element. Since `<google-youtube>` is in a lower stacking context than the header and drawer, the video's `z-index` alone won't be able to move it to the front.

To compensate, you could use the following CSS to move the `app-header` and `app-drawer` to a negative `z-index`, allowing `<google-youtube>`'s inner video to stack above them when fullscreen. *(This was tested on Chrome 56, Firefox 50, and Safari 10 on macOS Sierra)*

```
app-drawer-layout:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor app-header,
app-drawer-layout:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor app-drawer {
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

Note the `:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor` pseudo-class is applied to all ancestors of the fullscreen element (i.e., `<google-youtube>`'s video element) and is automatically removed when exiting fullscreen. This WebKit pseudo-class currently has no documentation that I could find. Note the Gecko equivalent ([`:-moz-full-screen-ancestor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-full-screen-ancestor)) was removed from Firefox 50, although `:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor` still works there.

Comment: Thanks for your help tony19 ! That worked perfectly, I had been playing with the z-index but was not targeting accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tristan No problem :)

Comment: Very useful - after spending so much time trying to fix `paper-dialogue` being obscured by `app-header` it's great to see that the content in my dialogue  can now go fullscreen.